# What would you name the different DTOs for the methods "GetUser" and "AddUser"?

Tags: c#, naming, web-services, soap

I have a web service with the methods `GetUser` and `AddUser`, and some DTOs (Data Transfer Objects)

- `GetUser`: retrieves user information, as a DTO called `UserGet`
- DTO `AddUser`: takes a DTO called `UserAdd`, and creates a new user

both DTOs inherit from the class `User`, but have different additional fields. outline:

```
class User
{}

class UserGet : User
{}

class UserAdd : User
{}
```

what are better class names?

Comment: `GetUserResponse` and `AddUserResponse`

Comment: @yitzih i'm assuming you would mean `AddUserRequest`

Comment: i'm also considering putting the classes in a separate namespace, from the methods

Comment: That inheritance should be removed. A DTO and their related domain object should not inherit from one another. The entire point of the DTO is to **decouple** the data from its domain, and by using inheritance you're undoing that purpose entirely. This is a case where you do not create shared ancestry just because two classes happen to have some similar properties.

Comment: Questions about naming really depend on context. For example, the act of adding a user could be seen as an “enrollment” or registration” request, if it comes from an end-user registering for the first time. But it might be called something else if it administrator is adding the user through a backend tool, or is merely adding a user to a tenant or permission group. You might also have several different actions that add a user that need to be distinguished from one another. The naming really depends on you and what is clear to you in the context of your line of business.

Comment: @JohnWu let's say the context is "enrollment" instead of "adding", then how would you name the `AddUser` method and the `UserAdd` class? it looks to me like further context is irrelevant. i didn't add much context to the question, because i'm looking for general solutions (i'm not even retrieving or creating users, but other data, to be honest)

Comment: @Flater thanks for the good observation. inheritance has been giving me so much trouble in this case, so i'm going to stop using that here

Comment: @symbiont I would probably name the method "Enroll" and the DTO would be named "EnrollDTO" or "EnrollRequest".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general approach is to add "DTO" to the end of the class name, as well as place all the DTOs in their own namespace. So, considering the above, you could name them `GetUserDTO` and `AddUserDTO` respectively.

Comment: that makes sense. what is your opinion on only changing the namespace and using the same name for the classes and methods?

Comment: In my opinion, then the distinction between class and method wouldn't be so clear to someone reading the code. It is a matter of promoting fast comprehension and development, and having different names for classes and methods helps achieve that.